# Python Kivy - How do I implement a button as an image while keeping the original image ratio?

Tags: python, image, button, kivy

I am making a photo lookup project using python kivy, and have been able to display images usable as buttons. However, the images are stretched. I am trying to make a program which will display the images as squares in a grid layout, while also keeping their aspect ratio (similar to how your photo library looks on your phone). Preferably, I'd like to have the button almost be like a preview of the actual photo, but I am clueless as to how to implement this after researching online. Either this, or just to just have the images displayed with their original aspect ratio.

```
imgname = Button(border=(0,0,0,0), background_normal=img, center_x=center_x, center_y=center_y)
```

I tried using this, which was successful in displaying the image (where img is the filepath of the img). I also tried:

```
imgname = Button(border=(0,0,0,0), background_normal=img, center_x=center_x, center_y=center_y, size=(100, 100))
```

and modified the size variable with size_hint, and setting different values from 100 to 0 to None for each x and y, but none of this worked.
Sorry for the lengthy question, any advice would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

In KV file you can create a custom widget/class like this:

```
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>
    allow_stretch: True
```

and you can use it like:

```
ImageButton:
    source: 'yourimage.png'
```